# Top(bar) Hat awarded for seemingly no reason

Tags: bug, winter-bash, winter-bash-2018

I just got the Top(bar) Hat on Stack Overflow. Why? According to the description, it is awarded if you:

> post a question that gets answered or earn reputation with an answer you post

I have not asked any questions or received reputation for answers on SO since Winterbash began, so there is no reason for me to have the hat. And yet I do.

Comment: Didn’t you earn any reputation because of an answer?

Comment: Maybe a new user answered one of your older questions but the answer got deleted in the review queues before you could see it?

Comment: You probably got an upvote on one of your two answers you posted today that was then undone again.

Comment: @MartijnPieters No upvote/upvote undone [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9445557/artemis-fowl?tab=reputation).

Comment: @ArtemisFowl You're history wont show an up vote that gets retracted if it happens fast enough.  You could have the perfect situation where you get up voted, hat script runs, awards hat, up vote retracted, history left empty.

Comment: Also, [an answer you posted 23 hours ago was up voted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53803724/interaction-while-time-sleep/53804109#53804109).  By the description that looks like it should count.

Comment: @NathanOliver Upvoted after the hat was awarded